# How can I configure to solo-mine, and use a mining-pool as failover?

Tags: wallet, mining-pools, cgminer

cgminer can be configured to have [multiple pools](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer).

Is there a way, to have as first entry my private wallet, and as second entry a public mining-pool?

Doing so gives strange output:

```
[2014-01-29 12:40:16] Probing for an alive pool
[2014-01-29 12:40:16] Network diff set to 2.46K
[2014-01-29 12:40:16] Block change for http://xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:9332 detection via stratum+tcp://freedom.wemineltc.com:3333 stratum
```

In my case, pool1 is my private wallet (xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa), pool2 is freedom.wemineltc.com. I wonder why pool2 shows up at all. Removing pool2 from cgminer.conf makes my cgminer work fine on pool1 / my private wallet.

Comment: You can set pool priorities with [`bfgminer`](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=877081.msg9686533#msg9686533). `bfgminer` is, imho, more advanced than `cgminer`.